# MS Dynamics AX 2012 transfer order

Tags: axapta

Our staff was going to transfer an items.

So, he created new transaction with transfer order no: "TO=00143" then click the "Posting - ship transfer order". The data wasn't display in the form and no error indicates aside from the "Warning sign/exclamation point".

(Please see the attached image below for your reference).

Alternative used: Checking of user accounts, re-installation and configuration of MS Dynamics AX 2012

"I am AX supporting staff, our System Administrator is on business trip."

Note: The other staff can do transfer order.

[Sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZxce.png)

[Sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj0aC.png)

Comment: This seems to be a functional question and not a programming related one. You will have better chances getting an answer in other communities such as the [AX forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33) of the Microsoft Dynamics Community or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: @FH-Inway, hello.. I already check the configuration, the processes and installation also I make his account as an admin. any other way to solve this? do you have any other suggestion? I already check it on the forum but I didn't find the solution, also I cant sign up because the site was blocked by our network admin. if you have seen or has an idea on how to fix this, I highly appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps to overcome window handle.

Goto Posting --> Ship Transfer Order --> then click on Default Values --> Change the Update from Ship Now to ALL...And then click on Edit Lines and Print.

Hope it helps.